# What is the difference between qMin and std::min?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the difference between [qMin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qMinx) (provided by the Qt Framework) and [std::min](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) (provided by the C++ standard library)?

Both seem to get the minimum of the two arguments.

Is there any difference between them? Why would I ever prefer to use one over the other?

Comment: Qt tend(ed) to be a framework not using `std`.

Comment: To find out you could take a look at the links you posted ;) For example `std::min` has overloads for passing an initializer list or a extern comparator. `qMin` has not.

Comment: another important thing is that `std::min` is in C++ standard so you can use it everywhere, unlike qMin which can be used only in Qt